# iPad mishandling route change speakers -> headphones

Tags: ios, ipad, ios4, core-audio

I'm running iOS 4.3.2.

1. I start my app on my iPad (nothing plugged in).
2. Audio works.
3. I plug in the headphones.
4. No audio, neither from the iPad, nor from the headphones.
5. I unplug the headphones, go to (2)

Alternatively:

1. I start my app on my iPad with the headphones plugged in.
2. Audio comes out of the headphones.
3. I unplug the headphones.
4. Now audio comes out of the iPad.
5. I plug in the headphones.
6. No audio, neither from the iPad, nor from the headphones.
7. I unlpug the headphones again, goto (4).

Here is my audio session code:

```
@implementation AudioSession

+ (void) CreateAudioSessionWithInterruptionListener: (AudioSessionInterruptionListener) interruptionListener 
                                returningSampleRate: (Float64 *) pHWSampleRate 
{
    OSStatus result = AudioSessionInitialize(NULL, NULL, interruptionListener, self);
    if (result != kAudioSessionNoError)
    {
        NSLog(@"AudioSessionInitialize(...) failed!");
        return;
    }

    SET_PROPERTY( kAudioSessionProperty_AudioCategory,                        UInt32,   kAudioSessionCategory_PlayAndRecord );
    SET_PROPERTY( kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideCategoryMixWithOthers,        UInt32,   (UInt32) YES                        );
    SET_PROPERTY( kAudioSessionProperty_PreferredHardwareIOBufferDuration,    Float32,  .005                                );

    // GET not set h/w sampleRate
    // Float64 hwSampleRate;
    // UInt32 size = sizeof(Float64);
    AssertOK(AudioSessionGetProperty(
                                     kAudioSessionProperty_CurrentHardwareSampleRate, 
                                     & (UInt32) { sizeof(Float64) }, 
                                     pHWSampleRate), 
             @"couldn't get hw sample rate");
    //NSAssert(size == sizeof(Float64);
    NSLog(@"H/W SampleRate: %d", (int) (* pHWSampleRate));

    AssertOK(AudioSessionSetActive(true), 
             @"couldn't set audio session active\n");
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I will update the question

Comment: How are you configuring your app's Audio Session?  Are you handling any AudioSession route change notifications?

Comment: @hotpaw2, updated... and no, no route-change handler code

Answer (score 1):

This might be an iOS bug in fact. I have the same issue when switching to HDMI output (also iOS 4.3). In 50% of all cases, the route change succeeds and audio comes out of the television instead of the iPad, as expected. In the other 50% of all cases, after plugging in the HDMI adapter, I have no audio at all, neither television, nor iPad. I get audio back as soon as I unlpug the adapter again.

So I cannot really offer you a nice solution, only a work-a-round. Register for audio route changes (by setting a property listener for the property kAudioSessionProperty_AudioRouteChange). When this callback fires, handle it, e.g. by re-initializing all your Core Audio stuff. This is not a very nice solution, but one that works.

**Update:**
In your special case, the system behaves pretty much how Apple says it shall behave. Let me quote from Apple's Interface Guidelines for iOS:

> The case for playback is similar but has different outcomes, as shown
>   on the right of the figure. If a user unplugs the headset during
>   playback, your callback should pause the audio. If a user plugs in the
>   headset during playback, your callback should simply allow playback to
>   continue.

So Apple says: Switching from internal speaker to headphone -> playback continues. Switching from headphone to internal speaker -> playback pauses. According to this quote this is a behavior you should implement on your own, not one that the system enforces for you, but it is pretty close to the behavior you are actually seeing, isn't it?